# php array_intersect is showing no intersection

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have two arrays $t1 and $t2.  When I print them out I get the following:

t1:

```
Array ( [0] => Christina Aguilera [1] => Iron Maiden [2] => Bob Marley )
```

t2:

```
Array ( [0] => Bob Marley )
```

I'm trying to get the common elements of the array though the array_intersect function, and I'm using the below line:

```
$intersection = array_intersect($t1,$t2);
```

However, for some reason when I print the result $intersection I get get:

```
Array ( )
```

Can anybody see what it is going wrong?  The code for my function is below but I think the above should be sufficient to work it out.

```
// For extra information
function findMutualInterests($_uProArray, $_tProArray)
{
    $_commonDetails = null;

    $_fieldNames = array_keys($_uProArray[0]);
    $_uProValues = array_values($_uProArray[0]);
    $_tProValues = array_values($_tProArray[0]);
    //print_r($_uProValues);

    // Iterate over the arrays and find ones in common
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_uProValues); $i++) {
        $t1 = explode(',',$_uProValues[$i]);
        print_r($t1);
        $t2 = explode(',',$_tProValues[$i]);
        print_r($t2);
        $intersection = array_intersect($t1,$t2);
        print_r($intersection);
        $_commonDetails[$_fieldNames[$i]] = implode($intersection);
    }
    return $_commonDetails;
}
```

EDIT:  Just thought I would point out that the output of $t1 and $t2 shown above are the output of a single iteration of the below function.  I just chose that one as an example.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have extra whitespace at the end maybe? Have you tried using `trim()` before inserting the values in the arrays?

Comment: hi netcoder - I'm not manually inserting the values into the arrays at any point.  The arrays are the result of an FQL query (Facebook query), so I assume that they have good form.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($intersection)`? `var_dump` shows the type and length of all variables.

Comment: Hi Jocelyn - the result of that line is: array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }

Comment: I'm sorry, what is actually needed is to check the output of `var_dump($t1);` and `var_dump($t2);`

Comment: Jocelyn, thank you!  I just tried that var_dump command on the other variables and there's a problem - a gap is appearing for some reason:  { [0]=> string(18) "Christina Aguilera" [1]=> string(12) " Iron Maiden" [2]=> string(11) " Bob Marley" } array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Bob Marley" } - Bob Marley and Iron Maiden have spaces before them but not Christina Aguilera - thanks!  I don't know why this is happening still though.

Comment: @user1058210: What do you mean you're not inserting them? What is `$t1 = explode(',',$_uProValues[$i]);` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your code works fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lowysV), try trimming input strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a huge mistake.
If you have more elements in `$_tProValues` than in `$_uProValues` you will not test all possibilities in the `$_tProValues` array. Then you'll not be able to test all possibilities. What happens here is exactly that, you're not testing all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments above, because this works just fine:

```
<?php

$a = array (
        0 => 'Christina Aguilera',
        1 => 'Iron Maiden',
        2 => 'Bob Marley'
    );

$b = array (
        0 => 'Bob Marley'
    );

$intersect = array_intersect( $a, $b );

print_r( $intersect );

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Bob Marley
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Check the code it is very useful for you ,because this works fine:**

$final_arr = [];
foreach ($a as $a_val) {
      foreach ($b as $b_val) {
        if(in_array(strtolower($a), array_map('strtolower', $b_val))){
            $final_arr[] = $b_val; 
            }
       }
    }
```